# Rewrite rule to a specific value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite this rule

`www.mydomain.it/?action=preventivo`

that becomes

`www.mydomain.it/preventivo`

I want to apply this rule only if the value of the variable action is preventivo. If not equal,  folders and files remain default.

I tried this rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?action=$1 [L]
```

but if I write

```
www.mydomain.it/promo
```

always see the index and not the page promo

Comment: Please review your question. Is it the action parameter or the section parameter? Are we looking at a value of promo or preventivo? Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: scusa, action is correct

Comment: You say you only want to apply it for preventivo, but then your test is for promo. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes if only the value is preventivo. Promo is the another page. When i write mydomain.it/another-pages i see the index, but i want to see the default html page